# POJ-2663 Tri Tiling problem: What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: java

http://poj.org/problem?id=2663

My output is right, I am 100% sure. I don't know why it is not accepting it.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Main 
{ 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        long a[]=new long [31];
        a[2]=3;
        a[4]=11;
        int i,j,s;
        for(i=6;i<31;i+=2){
            for(j=i-2;j>=2;j-=2){
                if(j==i-2){
                    a[i]+=a[j]*3;
                }
                else
                a[i]+=a[j]*2;
            }
            a[i]+=2;
        }
        while(true){
            s=sc.nextInt();
            if(s<0)
            break;
            if(s%2==0)
            System.out.println(a[s]);
            else
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are submitting the code in the expected format by the poj.org standards and guidelines? I tried to submit your code and received a 'Wrong Answer' message on this solution....

Comment: spelling, grammar, syntax highlighting

Comment: It is in standard input & output but i got it, in my code i have taken at 0 input 0 but in questionnaire's solution it is 1